# Why Typescript Map is not automatically indexable (& property-accessable) like Indexable Types?

Tags: typescript

So, in the typescript below code works:

```
interface CounterArray {
    [index: string]: number;
}

let myArray: CounterArray = {};
myArray["001"] = 0 
myArray["002"] = 0

console.log(myArray[0]) // should result 0
```

Got it. All good! But, if I do similarly to a Map.

```
const map = new Map<string, number>
map.set("001",0)
map.set("002",0)

console.log(map[0]) // Syntax error: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because type 'Map<number,string>' has no index signature.
```

Well I'm quite baffled by this, because, coming from Java/Kotlin/C#, Map by default should be index-able by key. And I think, such work should be done elegantly using `Map<key,value>`.

Moreover, using the "First code block above", I can do something like:

```
console.log(myArray["001"]++) // Should results 1
```

While I can't do something like this with the map counterpart

```
console.log(myArray.get("001")++) // Syntax error, Object is possibly undefined -> on editor level. So it's a syntax error. Not compile or other runtime error.
```

I think this behavior is weird. Or maybe it is expected? Maybe the `Map` I know (from Java/C#/Kotlin) is different than typescript's `Map`?

Thanks for your explanation!

Comment: Javascript's Map doesn't allow indexing access; you have to use `map.get`. The second error is that `Map<string,number>.get` returns a number _or_ undefined if that key isn't in the map, and you can't increment undefined.

Comment: @AlexGuerra hello. thanks for your response. But the second error pop on editor level. I haven't compile nor run it. In my real case, i've checked for existence of that value in that path. But still no good. the only way is get the current value (cast it to number), increment it, and reassign it. which is soo cumbersome and too many boilerplate code.

Comment: @MosesAprico actually the error for second case is _The operand of an increment or decrement operator must be a variable or a property access._ Check in [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html). Same error you'll get in C# by the way.